# Get all invoices assigned to a customer in Zoho Books

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

I'm trying to figure out how to query the Zoho Books API to get all of the invoices that have been assigned to a particular contact/customer. So far I'm not finding the documentation, but there has to be a way right? When customers login to the portal they can see their invoices, so it would make sense that I can get that information somehow.

Bonus points if I can also link that customer back to a Zoho CRM contact.

I'm basically building a simplified portal that shows the customer some CRM data as well as any outstanding invoices they have in Zoho Books.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve list of invoices, you have to pass **customer_id** in the [Invoice List](https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#Invoices_List_invoices) (`/api/v3/invoices?customer_id={customer_id}`) API.

If you have enabled Zoho CRM integration and whenever you create contacts in Zoho Books, it automatically sync with Zoho CRM. You can get the `zcrm_account_id` and `zcrm_contact_id` in Customers APIs and `zcrm_potential_id` and `zcrm_potential_name` in the Invoice APIs respectively.

Comment: So what would I do if I need to also get attachments from the customer in the CRM? Does the CRM API expose the Books ccustomer_id as well? Same customer, but I need all the data in both the CRM and Books programmatically

Comment: No. CRM won't expose Books customer id.

Comment: i want to get customer zoho invoices of certain month and year via api any help

Comment: You can use export api with date ranges 

`https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/export?entity=invoice&accept=csv&async=true&from_date={from}&to_date={to}